# SSRS Center and Resize External Image

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create a report and I have an image control that I want to link to a dynamic file name that comes from my database. Unfortunately, they can be various sizes but need to be centered and **resized instead of clipped** if they are too big. Is there a way to do this?  Using the External option on Images does not do all of this.

I am experimenting with using Custom Code to do the job but I am failing miserably.  I am trying to read the image into a Image variable using System.Drawing.Image.FromFile so I can resize it but I am running into Security issues, Uri issues, etc. so I'm not sure this is the correct way to go.

Comment: You should be able to use the Sizing property on the Image control in the SSRS Report Designer. Does that not work?

Comment: I did some research and am realizing the nature of your problem more completely. Have you read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx) on a possible fix? It won't solve the problem with getting the image from a URI to start with, but if that's your problem it might be best addressed in a new question more specific to that issue.

Comment: Yes that article is really the only thing I've found that was useful with my problem.  But it doesn't solve the problem with getting the image from a URI or the problem with centering and resizing large images.

Comment: I have the same problem, I think the alternative way is to store one more image with smaller scale in database, customize the paddingTop and paddingLeft during runtime, otherwise the image need to be scaled again and again when the report launches.